# Is there a way to select 'back' vertex/edges/faces without having to turn on x-ray?

Tags: shortcut

Say I'm on perspective view and some vertices on a cube are 'hidden' away from view and I want to select with the front vertices...I'd have to turn on x-ray, right? I just find it a unecessary step most of the time I'm modelling...can I turn this off?

Tks!

Comment: X-Ray isn't the best solution for similar case. Turning off Limit Selection To Visible, modeling with X-Mirror set to given axis or Mirror modificator to work only on half / quarter of mesh, sculpting mesh with Grab brushes with high radius might be better ones. Though it's not clear what is the certain problem with modelling as you mentioned

Comment: 2022 and this limitation thanks god for 3ds max

Comment: Is this some kind of a principal point of the Blender team? I really don't understand this. EVERY other 3d tool works like this. I don't need to see the backfaces - I KNOW what I am selecting and otherwise I turn around to be sure. It feels that this could be a simple setting and it's driving me mad for a further great tool.

Answer (score 6):

I may misinterpret what you say but:

- The shortcut to switch from *Solid* to *Wireframe* mode (and thus to grab a hidden vertex) is <kbd>Z</kbd> in 2.79 and <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> in 2.8.
- When you are in *Solid* mode you can activate/deactivate the *Limit Selection to Visible* (2.79) or *Show Whole Scene Transparent* option (2.8) on the horizontal menu bar.
- In 2.8, in both *Edit* or *Object* mode, use <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to switch to transparent/not transparent.

Comment: I understand, and no you didn`t misinterpret..I just really wanted the option of selecting hidden vertices without having to go to x-ray to be my default.

Comment: if you want to select a vertices behind, you need to see by transparency, no? And when you are in Solid mode you can activate/deactivate the Limit Selection to Visible (2.79) or Show Whole Scene Transparent option, so I'm still not sure what you lack or where is the problem

Comment: Is not necessarily a problem, I come from the fallen XSI and although I see there's an advantage in this procedure I never really needed or used it. In xsi the default drag box selection of polygons/vertices/edges gets everything in the way but it's only really used when you want to select a chunk of your model. If I want to select a group os polygons withoug selecting the back of geometry for example I can just 'paint' over them using polygon select tool. It may sound weird but it's incredibly fast and pratical;

Comment: Anyway, I feel like it's not just a matter of getting used to the tool, which has amazing features by the way but also unecessary steps that blender takes to approach simple tasks, like I'm on 'faces' selection mode so why can't I simply click and drag drawing over the polygons I want selected and insted I have to switch select tool-paint over-switch back to gizmo for example...You get what I mean?

Comment: Anyway, i was just wondering there might be a way around this...thanks for the help anyways! :)

Comment: hard to understand but sure, some things can be improved  ;)

Comment: I've edited my answer, alt Z allows you to quickly switch from transparent to non transparent in 2.8, in both Object and Edit modes.

Answer (score 1):

I use a free addon called BorderOcclusion, which mimics Modo's select-through functionality. Essentially it turns x-ray mode on automatically when you click and drag the right/middle/other mouse button. Works like a charm, no manual switching into another mode required.

Comment: where can we find this addon? Could you share a link? Maybe add a short explanation explanation of how to use it or a few screenshots of the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

I use the addon too , the Border Occlusion is the best addon for it

You can download the addon here -
https://github.com/Darcvizer/Border-Occlusion

Comment: The version of this plugin that works with 2.9 is here https://blenderartists.org/t/border-occlude/679738